# DynamoDb query ONLY by primary key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm pretty new to DynamoDB (NO Sql in general) and I'm having some troubles to understand how to form a simple query..

What I want to perform is a simple `SELECT FROM` in SQL but it seems I cannot get it done.

My table definition is basically:

Table name  snsNotifications
Primary partition key   recipientId (Number) <--- This is a user id
Primary sort key    snsID (String) <--- This is the SNS message id

it follows some attributes (like readAt).

The query I want to perform is:

```
SELECT from snsNotifications WHERE recipientId=X and readAt=x
```

I even can perform this query on AWS UI:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3h6r.png)

My lambda function uses the following :

```
var params = {
            TableName : "snsNotifications",
            KeyConditionExpression   : "recipientId = :recipientId and readAt = :readAt",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":recipientId": parseInt(msg.recipientId),
                ":readAt"     : 0,
            }
        };

        docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("Query succeeded.");
                data.Items.forEach(function(item) { ... }
```

But i get the following error:

> Unable to query. Error: {
>     "message": "Query condition missed key schema element: snsID",
>     "code": "ValidationException",
>     "time": "2017-11-20T18:19:40.419Z",
>     "requestId": "J73RIAE09GDRD1Q47I9OLCU7N7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
>     "statusCode": 400,
>     "retryable": false,
>     "retryDelay": 44.175697630271316
>   }

So basically it is complaining of snsID (primary sort key) being not defined on the query itself.

Any lights? I bet is just some small detail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace the readAt in KeyConditionExpression with snsId. If you dont want to include the sort key and wanted to filter the data by non-key attribute readAt, use FilterExpression for it.

KeyConditionExpression can have only partition key or sort key. For non key attributes, you should use FilterExpression.

Comment: that was the answer, nailed it!

Answer (score 9):

Thank you @notionquest, that made the trick.

Attached answer to who may help:

```
var params = {
            TableName : "snsNotifications",
            KeyConditionExpression   : "recipientId = :recipientId",
            FilterExpression: "readAt = :readAt",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":recipientId": parseInt(msg.recipientId),
                ":readAt"     : 0,
            }
        };
```